# Why is Hide and Show password feature not working in form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, show-hide

I was just trying to add a feature for showing password in my login form. I have tried couple of ways but it's still not working. I am not understanding why it's happening. Could anyone please help me?

```js
$(".toggle-password").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("fa-eye fa-eye-slash");
  var input = $($(this).attr("toggle"));
  if (input.attr("type") == "password") {
    input.attr("type", "text");
  } else {
    input.attr("type", "password");
  }
});

/**function showPwd(id, el) {
  let x = document.getElementById(id);
  if (x.type === "password") {
     x.type = "text";
     el.className = 'fas fa-eye-slash toggle-password';
} else {
    x.type = "password";
    el.className = 'fas fa-eye toggle-password';
    }
}**/

/**const togglePassword = document.querySelector('.toggle-password');
  const password = document.querySelector('#password-field');
  togglePassword.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  // toggle the type attribute
  const type = password.getAttribute('type') === 'password' ? 'text' : 'password';
  password.setAttribute('type', type);
  // toggle the eye / eye slash icon
  this.classList.toggle('fa-eye');
});**/
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="#" method="post">
  <input id="password-field" type="password" name="Password" value="Password" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Password';}" required="***" />
  <span toggle="#password-field" class="fas fa-eye-slash fa-eye field-icon toggle-password 
      hidepass">
    </span>
</form>
```

I have tried two different way too which I have comment out in script to make it work, but these are also not working. Please someone help.[here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Csp6.png)

Comment: Hi Emon, can you create a playground with your code to test it?

Answer (score 0):

Toggling the main class removes the ability to click it, so add a class which hides it using `opacity` making it still clickable.

```js
$(".toggle-password").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("hidden");
  var input = $($(this).attr("toggle"));
  if (input.attr("type") == "password") {
    input.attr("type", "text");
  } else {
    input.attr("type", "password");
  }
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  opacity: 0.2;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" method="post">
  <input id="password-field" type="password" name="Password" value="Password" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Password';}" required="***" />
  <span toggle="#password-field" class="fas fa-eye-slash fa-eye field-icon toggle-password 
  hidepass">
</span>
</form>
```

Comment: I have copied your script code and .hidden css. But still it's not working....